# Datasets for autonomous driving contains labels for classification

Tags: data-request, classification

I'm looking for Datasets for Autonomous Driving that contains labels for classification. Specifically, I'm looking for Dataset that has labels indicating if there is pedestrians in the image or not.
I want to create classifier which can identify if the image contains pedestrians (some people).
Anyone familiar with such dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Berkeley DeepDrive](https://bdd-data.berkeley.edu/) currently hosts the world's largest self-driving dataset, with 100,000 video sequences.

However, you should bear in mind that if you wish to download all of the data (including the videos), then the total file size will be over 1000 GB. If you are just looking to download the Info part of the dataset, then that will be just under 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

CityScapes contains such labels
https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/

Answer (score 0):

This portal has several open datasets for autonomous driving

https://scale.ai/open-datasets

> Index of Open Datasets for Autonomous Driving